# What href URL should I use so that AJAX function doesn't change url of page?

Tags: html, ajax

I am building a website that includes a feature like Facebook's "Like" button that allows users to click it and affect some backend and visible change without reloading the entire page. I have implemented AJAX calls and they are working fine.

FYI, the site is being built in Django/Python and I'm using the Dajaxice package to help me do the AJAX stuff (but that's really just incidental to this question)

Here is what my HTML code looks like:

```
<a id="myID" name="myID" href="#" onclick="Some_Fancy_AJAX_Stuff_Here;">Like</a>
```

What I don't like is that this page sits at http://www.mySite.com/index.html -- However when they click the link, the URL in the browser changes. An "#" gets appended to it. I don't like that. It doesn't happen on Facebook when I click "Like" so how can I get rid of that behavior here?

I tried replacing href="#" with href="." or href="", but that didn't work. I also tried simply removing href property from  tag completely. That did the trick, but it had the undesirable side-effect of removing the underline and link-coloring and mouse-hover-turns-to-hand.

So what's the cleanest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End the fancy AJAX stuff with `return false;` to prevent the default action of following the link.

Answer (score 1):

In the click handler you need to prevent the default action. When you're clicking an anchor that has an `href` value of `#`, it redirects the browser to an internal marker. You merely need to tell the anchor to do nothing:

```
var anchor = document.querySelector("#myID");

anchor.addEventListener("click", function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Proceed to make asynchronous request
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am building a website that includes a feature like Facebook's "Like" button

You said it yourself, use a `button` and not an `a`nchor.

So

```
<button id="myID" name="myID" onclick="Some_Fancy_AJAX_Stuff_Here;">Like</button>
```

Would be a *cleaner* way of doing it.

The cleanest way of doing it is by adding an event listener through Javascript.